# Filename Date Format SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, date-time

I am trying to change the filename date format for an InfoPath form generated item.

Currently I am using this file name formula: **concat("Backup", "-", today())**

Which results in this filename **Backup-2015-02-12**

However having changed my locale settings to United Kingdom the date format has changed for another field on my form but not on this one.

I need the file name to display as **Backup-12-02-2015**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

if you want date format in `dd-mm-yyyy` format although you changed local settings to United Kingdom you can use below formula:

```
concat("Backup", "-", substring(now(), 9, 2), "-", substring(now(), 6, 2), "-", substring(now(), 1, 4))
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is the solution I was looking for! :)

Comment: If it answers your question, mark it as answered by ticking the check mark.